# How to take in JSON as input to python tornado "post" method

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to use tornado to do a simple get and post method. Quite new to tornado framework. For the post I would like to take in a json as input, use that input to feed into another function that I have to execute another part of code. However I can't get tornado post method to work even with a simple self.write().

For my get method I am reading from an SQL database to get the status of a sensor and write that in a json format. The get method works perfectly! When I go to localhost:port# it reads out my get json file. For my post method I would like to take in a simple json of just one key:value which is a float number. I want to take that float number that the user specified in the json and use it in my flowMKS.set() function that will change the setpoint parameter of the sensor. I am not sure how to input a json into the post method and read it into a variable. I have some #commented code below that I tried and didn't work. However I went back to the basics and just did a self.write("Hello World") to see if the post was working. I can't get self.write to work either. Keep getting a 500 error message when i go to localhost:port#/flow_post. The variable flow_status was used in my get method.

The intended result would be to take in a json {"setpoint":45.5} into the post method. Use the number and insert into my flowMKS method to change a parameter on the sensor.

How would you take in a json to a post method and take the number from the json input and store in a variable?

```py
class Current(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self): 
        global flow_status
        time = flow_status[0]
        ip = flow_status[1]
        rate = flow_status[2]
        setp = flow_status[3]
        tempc = flow_status[4]

        status = {"flow_controller":{
                "time":time,
                "ip":ip,
                "rate_sccm":rate,
                "setpoint":setp,
                "temperature_c":tempc,
                }
        }

        self.write(status)


class Update(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

#    def prepare(self):
#        if self.request.haders["Content-Type"].startswith("application/json"):
#            self.json_args = json.loads(self.request.body)
#        else:
#            self.json_args = None



    def post(self):

#        #expecting body data to contain JSON so we use json.loads to decrypt the JSON into a dict
#        data = json.loads(self.request.body)
#        
#        #Getting what the setpoint should be
#        setpoint = self.json_args["setpoint"]
#        
#        #making the input a float
#        setpoint = float(setpoint)
#    
#        #setting up connection with sensor
#        flowMKS = FlowController(flow_status[1])
#            
#        #sending setpoint to sensor
#        flowMKS.set(setpoint)

        self.write("Hello World")





if __name__ == '__main__':
#    global flow_status

    #Below is creating the Tornado based API for get and post methods
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(
            handlers=[(r'/',Current), (r'/flow_post', Update)])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)


    #using PeriodicCallback to get info from the SQL database every 500 ms
    PeriodicCallback(get_sql_status,500).start()
    #starting the entire Tornado IOLoop
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: so you want to post JSON to your post method ?

Comment: Yes. I want to take in a JSON file, parse it to get the value, then use that value to input into another function that I have. I am quite new to the tornado framework.

Comment: JSON file or just JSON object ?

Comment: A JSON object would be okay. Really whichever is easier to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uploading a file using Tornado you can use this function [`tornado.httputil.parse_body_arguments`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.parse_body_arguments) which will split the uploaded file content in a dictionary `file_dict` and other arguments in the FormData in the `args_dict`.

**Sample code:**

```
import tornado.httputil
import tornado.web
import tornado.escape
import json
import os
import sys
import traceback

class FileHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def _return_response(self, request, message_to_be_returned: dict, status_code):
        """
        Returns formatted response back to client
        """
        try:
            request.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
            request.set_status(status_code)

            #If dictionary is not empty then write the dictionary directly into
            if(bool(message_to_be_returned)):
                request.write(message_to_be_returned)

            request.finish()
        except Exception:
            raise

    def set_default_headers(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_header('Content-Type','text/csv')
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")

    def post(self):
        """
        This function reads an uploaded file
        """    
        try:
            arg_dict = {}
            file_dict = {}

            tornado.httputil.parse_body_arguments(self.request.headers["Content-Type"], self.request.body, arg_dict, file_dict)
            uploaded_file = file_dict['TestFile'][0]

            if not uploaded_file:
                return self._return_response(self, { 'message': 'No test file uploaded, please upload a test file' }, 400)

            # File contents here
            file_contents = str(uploaded_file['body'], "utf-8")

            self.set_status(200)
            self.finish()

        except Exception as ex:
            return self._return_response(self, { "message": 'Could not complete the request because of some error at the server!', "cause": ex.args[0], "stack_trace": traceback.format_exc(sys.exc_info()) }, 500)
```

---

You can alternatively use [`tornado.escape.json_decode`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/escape.html#tornado.escape.json_decode) to deserialize the request body into a dictionary and do something with it.

**Sample code:**

```
import tornado.gen
import tornado.web
import tornado.escape
import json
import os
import sys
import traceback

class JSONHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def _return_response(self, request, message_to_be_returned: dict, status_code):
        """
        Returns formatted response back to client
        """
        try:
            request.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
            request.set_status(status_code)

            #If dictionary is not empty then write the dictionary directly into
            if(bool(message_to_be_returned)):
                request.write(message_to_be_returned)

            request.finish()
        except Exception:
            raise

    def set_default_headers(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")

    def post(self):
        """
        This function parses the request body and does something
        """    
        try:
            # Do something with request body
            request_payload = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)

            return self._return_response(self, request_payload, 200)

        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            return self._return_response(self, { "message": 'Cannot decode request body!' }, 400)

        except Exception as ex:
            return self._return_response(self, { "message": 'Could not complete the request because of some error at the server!', "cause": ex.args[0], "stack_trace": traceback.format_exc(sys.exc_info()) }, 500)
```

Comment: I tried your second sample code example and it worked. However when I try to do something with the variable request_payload, it fails. 


For example I tried:
`request_payload = tornado.escape.json_decode(self.request.body)
setpoint = request_payload["setpoint"]`

Then changed 
`return self._return_response(self, setpoint, 200)`


I still get a 500 error though. The json object that I posted {"setpoint":45}
If I leave it as return request_payload it works.

Comment: `return self._return_response(self, setpoint, 200)` wrap it in a dictionary and send it

Comment: what is  `TestFile`  in post method?

Comment: @LuisFelipe `TestFile` is the name of formData key which you will use to upload the files